# How to change SelectedIndex in MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm

The following code (code-behind) is working:

```
DemoList.SelectedIndex = 3;
```

This one is not (MVVM):

```
 private int _SelectedItem;

        public int SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _SelectedItem; }
            set { _SelectedItem = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedItem"); }
        }

<...>
ChangeSelection = new DelegateCommand(Changing);
<...>
  public ICommand ChangeSelection { get; private set; }

<...>
    public void Changing()
        {
            SelectedItem = 5;
            MessageBox.Show(("something"));
        }
```

The MessageBox is just to confirm that the button command is working. (and It is) so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

XAML:

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

Comment: Using command is still valid MVVM as long as you remove `MessageBox.Show`

Answer (score 0):

try Mode.

```
 SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay,IsAsync=True}"
```

Comment: The problem was that I did not add "INotifyPropertyChanged" in my class.